# Window resizing causes text to overflow bootstrap button boundaries or button spills out of div area

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Buttons are fine until I resize window to be very small or in my case, look at the site on a small screen device such as mobile phone.

I want two different scenarios. One in which an area holds buttons that are equal in width but then when I size the window down the contents of the button spill out of the button.
I also want another area that has buttons that adjust to the size of the text. In this scenario, the text does not spill out of the buttons but now the buttons are spilling out of the div area.
I was trying everything I could think of which is why one area uses `<a href=""></a>` and the other uses `<button></button>`
Both scenarios are in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/leopardy/VFNmC/

[image]

The code from the fiddle:
html

```
<div class="combo">
<div id="button-area-1"> 
    <div><a href=""  class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-no-width">txt <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span></a></div>
    <div><a href=""  class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-no-width">txt txt <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span></a></div>
    <div><a href=""  class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-no-width">txt txt txt <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span></a></div>
    <div><a href=""  class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-no-width">txt txt txt txt <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span></a></div>
</div>

<div id="button-area-2">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-has-width">hi<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-has-width">hi hi<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-has-width">hi hi hi<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-has-width">hi hi hi hi<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span></button>
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
    .combo {
       position: relative;
       width: 100%;
       height: 400px;
       background-color: blue;
    }

    #button-area-1 {
       position:absolute;
       top:40%;
       left:60%;
       z-index: 2;
       background-color: #606060;
       background-color: rgba(96,96,96,0.5);
       border: 1px solid grey;
       outline: 1px solid darkgrey;
       width: 30%;
       padding-top: 1%;
       padding-bottom: 1%;
    }

    #button-area-2 {
       position:absolute;
       top:5%;
       left:60%;
       z-index: 2;
       background-color: @medium-gray;
       background-color: rgba(96,96,96,0.5);
       border: 1px solid grey;
       outline: 1px solid darkgrey;
       width: 30%;
       padding-top: 1%;
       padding-bottom: 1%;
    }

    .btn-no-width {
      margin-top:1%;
      margin-left: 10%;
      margin-right: 10%;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
    }

    .btn-has-width {
      width: 80%;
      margin-top:1%;
      margin-left: 10%;
      margin-right: 10%;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
    }
```

Comment: You need to use @media queries in your css to define different styles for different browser sizes.

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `min-width`(150px should do for your example) for `#button-area-1` and `#button-area-2`. But keep in mind this doesn't work on IE6 or less (not like it's still in use).

Comment: This fixed the content not spilling out of the buttons but now the entire div area that contains the buttons spills out of its outer div area :/

Comment: Actually didn't work for `<button>` See updated fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/leopardy/faF49/2/

Comment: @snowleopard for the big button you would need min-width:220px;

Comment: @snowleopard and instead of `left:60%;` try `right:10px;` (or whatever suits you) or you can check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/faF49/3/

Comment: Mysterious. Changing the css to have `left:` instead of `right:` as you suggested fixes the problem with the entire div area that contains the buttons spilling out of the outer div. I just wished I knew why.
Also, though doing `min-width:220px` on the div that holds the button with longest text does prevent the contents of button from spilling out, I didn't want to have to accommodate width based on button content so I added `white-space: normal;` on the buttons themselves to allow text to go to next line which increased button height but that's fine. Thanks for you help. Much appreciated.

Comment: @snowleopard when you set a div with right:60% but the width of the div is larger than 40% of its container it will spill out the it. Hope it helps.